# how to use one formula field in another formula field in crystals report

Tags: crystal-reports

my table as below

```
account_name debit_balance credit_balance
abc            100          50
pqr            80           100
xyz             150          90
```

I create one formula as below

```
Amount=(debit_balance-credit_balance)
```

now i want sum of all amount that is

### Sum(@amount)

I try As below
Sum(debit_balance-credit_balance) but it not work
I find solution on net but not get

Reply if u have any solution

Answer (score 0):

When you make one formula, you can't do any more summarizes of that calculated field (formula). That's why your first solution didn't work `Sum(@amount)`

Other solution `Amount=(debit_balance-credit_balance)`didn't work because you can make sum only for 1 field and you trying to make sum of 2 fields.

So solution for your problem is that just do a new formula  `Amount = sum(debit_balance) - sum(credit_balance)` where you make 2 summarizes of each fields and subtract them.

Hope it helps

Comment: glad it helped you... you can accept the answer btw ^^

Comment: There is another better solution ,Use running field total in crystal report so that get total of formula running field

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't your original problem and question.